# Google Calendar: How to quickly make several duplicates of an event?

Tags: google-calendar

In Google Calendar, what's the quickest way to make several duplicates of an event on different days if the events all have the same start and end times? (Assuming one doesn't want a recurring event, or the days do not conform to a simple pattern).

Currently I do the following from the 'Month' view, which must be repeated in entirety for each duplicate that I want:

1. Click initial event (pops up a 'bubble' of information)
2. Click 'Edit event details'
3. Choose 'More actions -> duplicate event'
4. Change the date
5. Save (this closes the event details, so I can't simply choose to duplicate this event again)

Is there a quicker way? Perhaps a method entirely from the 'Month' view?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

First, you can save yourself a step by double-clicking on the event at your step 1., as this will go directly to 'Edit event details'.

But I suggest you reconsider use of the repeat option for the event.  Say you want four identical events, but they occur in a irregular pattern of days.  When creating the first event, choose "Repeat", Daily, Ends after 4 occurrences.  Then, after you Save and end back in the Month view, find one of the events that is shown falling on a wrong day, and click-drag it to the right day.  Do that for any other of the occurrences which are not on the right day.  This should do the job.  The occurrences are still (sort of) part of a repeat group, but the ones that were moved have a note about the change in their details.

Comment: It's a very clever work-around (thanks!), but actually not an answer. For me, I'd liked the question to still be 'unanswered'.

Comment: (Sorry for comment, I don't have enough reputation) I have developed a Chrome extension to quickly duplicate events, I think it's excatly what you asked for. If you want check it out https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-calendar-quick-dup/belnijodgolpgmpahmdkjbjehbobnfpd?hl=en&authuser=0