# How to make many duplicates of an event in Google calendar which are easily modified by others

Tags: google-calendar

In a way similar to [Google Calendar: How to quickly make several duplicates of an event?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/12010/google-calendar-how-to-quickly-make-several-duplicates-of-an-event), I need to make many copies of events. However, it is important that they remain individual events (not part of a series), and so the answer to that question isn't appropriate.

I need them to be individual events because many people will have access to this calendar and will be able to change events. The calendar holds a rota, saying who is doing what, when. Everyone on the rota is free to arrange their own swaps, but I know from experience that if you allow a wide group of people edit on repeating events, it is easy for the whole series to be changed by accident. So I want each event to be an individual.

Comment: I don't have a fully fleshed-out answer for you, but what I'd probably do is lookup the iCalendar format and create a text file using that. Then clone the text file and make whatever other modifications are needed to each individual event, then import them into GCal.